# how to get the existing usernames from LAN in java

Tags: java, lan

I want to get all the usernames or IPaddresses from the LAN using java.
Can anyone suggest me how to approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Are all of your users part of a common domain? And does your domain has DNS or Directory Server which you can access? If so you could use JNDI either to access DNS server for IPAddress list and Directory Server for Users list.

Comment: sorry i dont want users can i get the system or computer names connected in lan.My computers are under same workgroup

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly strange question. What is your purpose, what do you want to do with the information? A list of user names is quite different from a list of IP addresses, it's hard to understand why either is acceptable.

Also, consider that just because an IP address "exists" on a LAN, that doesn't say anything about the type of host that has the IP address. It might not have a "user" associated with it, for instance.

For a list of IPs, try finding the [subnetwork mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork), and pinging the [broadcast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).

Comment: sorry i thought i dont want user names.can i get the System names or computer names connected to LAN where all the sytems are under the same workgroup

Comment: can anyone suggest me how to get the system names connected in Lan

Thank you!!